# How do you detach a Backbone view from an element without affecting the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

We are using Backbone views to enhance our app, and the architecture of our application dictates that we attach our views to existing DOM elements.

We recently encountered a situation in which it is necessary to detach a Backbone view from a DOM element without removing the DOM element itself. Thus, we cannot use `View.remove()` since it will in turn invoke `this.$el.remove()`;

I had originally created the following method for detaching the view, but I am concerned that I may be causing a memory leak:

```
detach: function() {
  this.stopListening();
  this.unbind();
  this.setElement(null);
}
```

This effectively replaces the View's element with empty jQuery object, and it unbinds all Backbone events. However, it occurred to me that jQuery might be storing a reference to the new empty object. I am not entirely clear on jQuery's internals so I can't comment on the effectiveness of this method.

I then modified the method as follows:

```
detach: function() {
  this.stopListening();
  this.unbind();
  this.undelegateEvents();
  this.el = null;
  this.$el = null;
}
```

I think this better achieves the desired result as it removes all references to the DOM and to jQuery. I am not 100% confident in this approach, so I was wondering how others have handled this scenario.

**Does this method seem sound? Is there a better way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

Extend the View and override remove so that it no longer calls this.$el.remove();

Example

```
var EnhanceView = Backbone.View.extend({
 remove: function() {
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
 }
});
```

should be as simple as that.

Comment: Will this view get cleaned up by the garbage collector since it still has a reference to a jQuery element?

Comment: Deleting references is never going to hurt. But I cannot say for certain how the GC will handle his (and don't have the time to find out). I would say use the delete on .$el and use the remove method to stay more inline with the original Backbone flow.

Comment: I think you'd need to `undelegateEvents` as well, otherwise there will still be a jQuery `on` attached to the view's `el`.